# How to get URL from which jnlp was run?

Tags: java, jnlp

For my Java Web Start app I want to restrict that it can be run only from the specified domain. How can I get URL from which my app was run? I tried this way:

```
final BasicService bs = (BasicService) ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");
final URL codeBase = bs.getCodeBase();
```

It works fine and shows me the origin but only when the codebase parameter in my jnlp file is empty. When it is set, then it shows the url for the codebase, which is wrong (when I host libs on other server) because I want the url from where my jnlp was run. For example I run my jnlp from "www.jnlpdomain.com", but the codebase is "www.libdomain.com" - in this case I would like to know the first url. When I check java console logs I can see following:

```
JNLP Ref (absolute): www.jnlpdomain.com/my_jnlp_file.jnlp
.... (some few lines)
=====CODEBASE=====: www.libdomain.com (this line is printed by me with the bs.getCodeBase())
```

So I can see that the host name is printed correctly in the first line in logs, starting with:

```
JNLP Ref (absolute): ....
```

How can I get this in my app, so I can validate the domain?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [JAR File Manifest Attributes for Security: Codebase Attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html#codebase):

> The `Codebase` attribute is used to restrict the code base of the JAR file to specific domains. Use this attribute **to prevent someone from re-deploying your application on another website** for malicious purposes.

Comment: I know, but this means that I will need to prepare a custom build for each client. I would like to avoid this and have just one general build which will work for each client, but still check if they use it properly (under specific domain).

Comment: *"this means that I will need to prepare a custom build for each client."* It comes down to a single line in the build file! You make it sound difficult..

Comment: It is some kind of solution for me, but still I would like to know where does this hostname in "JNLP Ref (absolute) ..." come from and if it's accessible for me in the java code.

Comment: It seems you are trying to achieve an aim use a less optimal approach. Good luck with it..

Comment: Why is it less optimal? If I could have a generic version of my app and check on which domain it is used - then it's more optimal for me than preparing a build for each client. Other question is if it's possible, but if yes, then it's better solution for me.

Comment: Let's imagine we have 200 clients. If I upgrade a version of my app I need to make 200 builds and distribute it to my clients. It would be easier to make one generic build and distribute it.